# Posts with Custom Fields does not appear

Tags: php

Plugin used: Types

I have created posts with Custom Posts and the regular Posts by Wordpress. However, the custom posts does not appear on the website. Only the regular posts appears.

Here I have created Custom Posts:
[image: Custom Posts]

Here I have created posts with the regular Wordpress posting:
[image: Wordpress Posts]

Here are the 2 latest posts within the category 9 (Featured) supposed to be shown:
[image: 2 latest posts within the category 9]

As you see, it does not show the one made with Custom Post. This is not the only example, but this is the easiest one to explain.

**Code**

```
        <div class="col-md-12 myeluft">
            <?php
                $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=2' );
                while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();     
            ?>  
            <div class="featured-post">
                <ul>    
                    <li>
                        <div class="col-md-5 featuredimage myeluftned"> 
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'singlepost-thumb' ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 myeluftned">
                            <h2 class="nomargintop blacklink">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="light offblack">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                <button class="btn thin luft" type="button">Se prosjekt</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr class="myeluft clearboth">
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div></div>
```

Anyone?

I will post detailed if you want, I just need to know what you want to know.

Is there a function I need to make Custom Fields Post to work?

**Suggestions:**

- Functions.php, something is wrong here
- Types, something is wrong the setup

Comment: Check if the post type `publicly_queryable` is set to `true` or `false`

Comment: Thank you. I can see a hook by publicly queryable, so I believe it means its set to true

Comment: @olen If a regular post have custom fields the post should be shown, even if the code for retreiving custom fields are not implemented. Custom fields and custom post type are different. On query you must query post_type="your-custom" if exist any different to normal post, and to retreive custom fields use the code **$your-string = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your-custom-field', true);**

Comment: Exactly what "Custom Fields" created the posts? Plugin? What? And exactly what does it do?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I will update the post right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by making it display all post types:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => 9,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_type' => 'any',
);
new WP_Query($args);
```